# Fast formula to get the range a number is in, given a perfect binary subdivision?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Mind the set of positive integers from `0` til `L` exclusive. For any positive integer `n` up to `log2(K)`, can split the set in `2^n` consecutive subsets of equal length. For example, for `L = 256`, `n = 3`, we'd get `2^3`, or `8`, subsets: `{0..31}, {32..63}, {64..95}, {96..127}, {128..160}, {160..191}, {192..223}, {224..255}`.

Let `f(L,n,i) : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> (Nat,Nat)` return, given an arbitrary `L` and `n`, the subset that some `i` is contained in. For example, for `f(256,3,100) = (96,127)`, because, if we divide the `0..255` range in `2^3` subsets, then number `100` is contained in the subset ranging from `96` to `127`.

My question is, what is a fast implementation of `f`? I wonder if it is possible to do so in constant time, with just a few bitwise operations.

Comment: Oh, I think it should be pretty simple actually - just compute the length of each subset, divide `i` by it, floor and multiply again. Will delete this question if that's the case.

Comment: Post the answer instead, if you find a solution - I am interested in this

Comment: Posting, but it isn't question-worthy IMO, for some weird reason I thought I'd need a slow recursive function for that.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int a, b; } pair;

pair f(int L, int n, int i) {
    int len = L / (1 << n);
    int a = i / len * len;
    return (pair) { a, a + len - 1 };
}

int main() {
    pair p = f(256, 3, 100);
    printf("%d %d\n", p.a, p.b);
}
```

I am not good with floating point, but looping works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct { double a, b; } paird;

paird fd(double L, double n, double i) {
    double len = L / pow(2, n);
    double a = 0, b;
    while (b = a + len, b < i) {
        a = b;
    }
    return (paird){ a, b };
}

int main() {
    paird p = fd(127, 7, 100);
    printf("%f %f\n", p.a, p.b); // (99.218750, 100.210938)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite obviously, just compute the length of each subset (`l`), divide `i` by `l`, and take the floor `k`. The desired range goes from `l*k` to `l*(k+1)-1`. In JavaScript:

```js
function subrange_of_i(L, n, i) {
  var l = L / (2 ** n); // or just `L >>> n`
  var k = Math.floor(i / l);
  return [l*k, l*(k+1)-1];
};
```

(TODO: convert to C for the sake of this answer.)